# Proportion of "nice" twisted Edwards curve at given finite field size

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

I am trying to generate a "nice" Montgomery elliptic curve on a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ such that its birational equivalent twisted Edwards curve has nice properties (for cryptographic application). I am following the approach of the algorithm given in Appendix 1 of [Elliptic Curves for Security](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7748#appendix-A.1) i.e.:

- $q$ is prime
- $q \equiv 1 \mod(4)$
- The Edwards curve has exact cofactor $8$ (i.e. $ord(Ed_q) = 8.r$ with $r$ prime)
- The twist has exact cofactor $4$ (i.e. $ord(Ed_q) = 8.r$ with $r$ prime)

My experiments so far have reached $A = 220000$ without success. I was hence wondering about the chance of success of finding a curve with suitable properties. Are there any heuristic or conjecture about the proportion of such twisted Edwards curve on a field of prime characteristic? I could not find any related content in the litterature.

If that can be of any help, my prime $q$ is not completely random at a given bit length as it must satisfy some criteria, especially having a large power of two root of unity ( $q - 1 \equiv 0 \mod 2^{\alpha}$) but I'd be happy with some results for random prime $q$.

Comment: Please define $Ed_q$ and $A$ in a clear manner, best with full references for the structure, the associated Weierstraß curve, and the orders of the two curves. We have no information on own tries, nothing to start with. The Appendix 1 is not a starting point, but an end point, potential answerers have to read it inside a memo formatted in the spirit of 1970. Moreover, the final help seems to be a further restriction on the $q$ to be searched. Please edit to have a well defined question. Please show and share the unsuccessful attempts and explain in an example what fails from the wish list.